# data table vuetify events and rendering is not proper for row per page drop down

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I facing issue with 'rows per page' drop down rendering and events for it. When I click on v-menu of table footer, drop down renders outside the screen due to CSS property 'top' is incorrectly calculated via vuetify js data table.

[image: Drop down]

There are 3 values in 'rows per page' drop down [5, 10, 15], 5 and 10 is visible but 15 is outside of the screen. there is no bottom padding or margin in table and height is also 100%.

Another issue is, when I click outside of drop down and some where in table, drop down didn't gets closed. It is only gets closed when click on drop down values.

I am using vuejs-2.5.13 with vuetify-1.1.13.

Comment: Can you quickly craft a JSfiddle so we can work on actual code ?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

I just checked one of [Vuetify's examples](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdata-tables%2F) and there is no such issue. You can compare your configuration and styles with this one.

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :sort-by="['calories', 'fat']"
      :sort-desc="[false, true]"
      multi-sort
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 200,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',

        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be due to the footer present at the bottom(I can see some black colored block) for which the z-index value might be higher. Due to which the dropdown is going below that footer.

Change the z-index value of the block to 0 and check If it works fine.